# Como inflar um botão dentro de um Item de ListView?

Tags: android

Eu preciso colocar um botão dentro um item de um ListView para ficar igual da imagem abaixo: [image: Botão dentro do listView]

Porém estou fazendo tudo dinamicamente, recebo um vetor com dados do banco e preencho as linhas da ListView. Alguém sabe como inserir um botão para cada linha da listView? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer tudo de forma dinamica e usando uma lista personalizada é necessário criar um xml apenas para um item dessa listView que será usado em todos os outros campos da lista. O segundo passo necessário para criar essa lista é criar uma variável do tipo `ArrayList<suaclasse>` com a classe de dados que você criou para preencher dinamicamente cada linha da sua lista.

Para criar seu xml especifico para cada linha tente algo como:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_texto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_botao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="CliqueBotao"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Após isso na sua classe principal você precisa criar uma classe que estende a classe BaseAdapter para que você possa inflar esse layout. E para isso a melhor pratica a ser utilizada é o design pattern MyViewHolder onde você pode dar uma olhada nesse link para saber mais disso: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Agora vamos criar a sua classe para poder inserir o texto tanto no TextView como no Button:

```
class SuaClasse{
    public String TvTitulo, BtTitulo;
    SuaClasse(String tv_titulo, String bt_titulo){
        this.TvTitulo = tv_titulo;
        this.BtTitulo = bt_titulo;
    }
}
```

Agora para que possamos manipular os dados usando o xml criado temos que criar uma classe para localizar os widgets do xml para cada linha:

```
class MinhaViewHolder{
    TextView tv_texto;
    Button bt_botao;
    MinhaViewHolder(View v){
        tv_texto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_texto);
        bt_botao = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bt_botao);
    }
}
```

Agora enfim devemos criar a class que estende o BaseAdapter da seguinte forma:

```
class MeuAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context c;
    MeuAdapter(Context context){
        this.c = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();//retorna o tamanho da lista
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);//retorna um item da lista
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;//retorna a posição de um item
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        MinhaViewHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
            holder = new MinhaViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (MinhaViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_texto.setText(lista.get(position).TvTitulo);
        holder.bt_botao.setText(lista.get(position).BtTitulo);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Agora para adicionar os itens nessa lista é necessário inicializar a lista e depois adicionar itens nela:

```
lista = new ArrayList<SuaClasse>();
lista.add(new SuaClasse("texto 1", "clique 1"));
lista.add(new SuaClasse("texto 2", "clique 2"));
```

E depois no seu método onCreate dizer que o adapter da sua lista será o adapter que foi criado para fazer essa lista:

```
adapter = new MeuAdapter(getApplicationContext());
lv_lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Na sua Activity também deve ter a função CliqueBotao para que ao clicar no botão ele realiza alguma ação:

```
public void CliqueBotao(View v){
    //Seu código aqui
}
```

Feito isso você pode sempre adicionar itens na sua lista, caso você precise de um novo item na lista após a lista estar pronta, você pode simplesmente adicionar o novo item e chamar o método notifyDataSetChanged da sua variável adapter da seguinte forma:

```
lista.add(new SuaClasse("texto 3", "clique 3"));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Espero que isso te ajude.

Answer (score -1):

Espero que isso lhe ajude,

http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Obrigado

Comment: Leonardo, procure usar os comentários para agregar alguma coisa a pergunta, se possivel poste aqui como é feito, links tentem a ficar fora por algum motivo.